# Provide Print functionality in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view with HTML tables, filled with information that I want to print in ASP.NET MVC 4 and C#.

I don't know the actual code that prints the document, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Print manually in the browser or create for example a PDF and send it to a printer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well you have two choices

1. Either use JS

   `<a href="javascript:window.print()">Click to Print This Page</a>`
2. [Or print to a PDF using Action Result in MVC](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/asp.net-mvc-action-results-and-pdf-content/)

For the JS option you will want to build a [print css](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml) file so as to best render the page during printing, also hide some element that you don't need to appear - menus for example.

Comment: For some reason the editor window didn't want to format the code properly... Feel free to edit it, may be a chrome issue?

Comment: how can i print a div only(in case i dont want to include the menus and other thing came from master page)..

Comment: If you check that print css link and look at the Remove unwanted items section, essentially you have a .noprint {display: none;} class and put that on all the items you don't want to show. Then put .noprint only in your print stylesheet.