# How to hide content on printing with MVC and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, printing

The title is obvious i think. This is where i got some infos :

[Provide Print functionality in ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544371/provide-print-functionality-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

[How do I hide an element when printing a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page)

first, css :

```
@media print
{
    .no-print, .no-print *
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

so, in my cshtml :

```
<td style="max-width: 100px;"><a href="javascript:window.print()" class="btn btn-default">Print</a>
```

and now things i don't want to print :

```
<div style="top:120px;left:10px;position:absolute;" class="no-print"></div>
```

I also tried `class="noPrint"`

All's good, exept in the preview before printing i still see my menu...so i guess it WILL be printed... I use chrome.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information you've provided, I can't see any reason why the print media queries wouldn't execute and prevent the menu from being printed. Take a look at the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozts2xgm/) that exposes this markup:

```
<td style="max-width: 100px;">
  <a href="javascript:window.print()" class="btn btn-default">Print</a>
</td>

<div style="top:120px;left:10px;position:absolute;" class="no-print">
  Won't print this!
  <span>Or this!</span>
</div>
```

It shows the basic elements you provided, and printing appears to hide the elements correctly.

Could you provide a little more detail? Maybe something else is going on that's exposing those elements or maybe the CSS hasn't been saved- something along these lines.

Comment: css not saved... i'm lame

Comment: Not lame at all - better to find out than to waste time in CSS docs!

Comment: Sure, at least you lightened me

Comment: Ho no wait, it also make my menu disapear while i'm navigating !

Comment: Strange - is your application locally hosted? Are there any other CSS selectors targeting those elements?

Comment: localy hosted yes, does it cahnges anything?

Comment: Because live on the server it dosen't show the menu either

Comment: I don't think it would change anything. Could you provide a link to the live site potentially? It may be difficult to find out what's going on, I think maybe some other element is being hidden in your CSS.

Comment: This didnt work for me in my own application. Should i just put the "@media" thing at the end of the css file? Or does it need to be in some kind of scope or something?

Answer (score 1):

I think this question may have to do with conflicting '@' symbols.  I saw in another SO post they talked about the @@ over-ride and said it needed a space after the double @@.  For me, that didn't work with the space, but this worked:

```
    <style>
        @@media print
        {
            .no-print { display: none !important; };
        }
    </style>
```

I then added the .no-print class where it was needed.

Comment: hmm, is this supposed to be in the "CSS" file? Why is there HTML syntax?